# Подскажите что с переменной ls! `ls+=c` вызывает ошибку: local variable 'ls' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

```
def min():
    for i in c2:
        a,b=srsumm(i)#summ/count
        c=a//b#average
        ls+=c#round(c,1)
    print(ls)
    return ls
```

Пишет, что *local variable 'ls' referenced before assignment*. Но ведь объявлять их не нужно заранее.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Переменную объявлять не нужно. Но у Вас оператор `+=`, т.е. он прибавляет к уже имеющемуся значению другое число. Т.е., фактически

```
ls += c <==> ls = ls + c
```

Из этой записи видно, что вначале будет взято значение `ls`, а только потом изменено и присвоено. Поэтому сообщение интерпретатора абсолютно верно.

Answer (score -4):

Насколько я знаю, нужно её объявить в цикле.

Напишите `global ls` в цикле.

Comment: все решилось объявлением ее в min(ls=0) - установкой по дефолту т.с.

Comment: @Evgen `global` - очень плохой тон!

Comment: @ALPHA, объявлять нужно не в параметрах, а в самой функции, просто ls=0.